# System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stack-overflow, c#-2.0

please help me regarding System.StackOverflowException
i m desing a .aspx to write records into the database i used 4-tier archietecture to implement this everything are working but when im compiling the page then its displyae the fields to insert the data ,when i insert the data to those field and clik the submitt button then its showes System.StackOverflowException occured

```
public class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        int CustomerID = 0;
        string Fname = string.Empty;
        string Lname = string.Empty;
        string Country = string.Empty;
    }
    public int CustomerID
    {
        get { return CustomerID; }
        set { CustomerID = value; }
    }
    public string Fname
    {
        get { return Fname; }
        set { Fname = value; }****
    }
    public string Lname
    {
        get { return Lname; }
        set { Lname = value; }
    }
    public string Country
    {
        get { return Country; }
        set { Country = value; }
    }
```

When page is executing  a window is popuped and displayed System.StackOverflowException occured please give me anyone solution to this problem

Comment: Please try and use markdown to format the code in your question so we can read it.

Comment: Additionally, I don't see anything in the code that would be able to cause a stack overflow, so can you please post your exception stack trace?

Comment: Please provide us with the code you use when the submit button is clicked. Also, please reformat your post (the code).

Answer (score 16):

```
public int CustomerID
{
    get { return CustomerID; }
    set { CustomerID = value; }
}
```

You are assigning the value to itself recursively. And the same for the other properties.

You need to define a backup field with another name, for example:

```
private int _CustomerId;
public int CustomerID
{
    get { return _CustomerID; }
    set { _CustomerID = value; }
}
```

Or even better:

```
public int CustomerId {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is infinite recusrive calls in your properties Get & Set like:

```
string Lname{ 
    get { return Lname; } 
    set { Lname = value; }
}
```

Lname = value; will call your property again & again.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public class Customers
{

    private int _CustomerID; 
    private string _Fname;
    private string _Lname;
    private string _Country;

    public Customers()    
    {        
        int CustomerID = 0;        
        string Fname = string.Empty;        
        string Lname = string.Empty;        
        string Country = string.Empty;    
    }    

    public int CustomerID    
    {        
        get { return _CustomerID; }        
        set { _CustomerID = value; }    
    }    

    public string Fname    
    {        
        get { return _Fname; }        
        set { _Fname = value; }
    }    

    public string Lname    
    {        
        get { return _Lname; }        
        set { _Lname = value; }    
    }    

    public string Country    
    {        
        get { return _Country; }        
        set { _Country = value; }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Customers()
    {
        int CustomerID = 0;
        string Fname = string.Empty;
        string Lname = string.Empty;
        string Country = string.Empty;
    }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string Fname { get; set; }

    public string Lname { get; set; }

    public string Country  { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: @Kobi It does when you use VS2008 (even targeting .NET 2.0)