# Return the current instance value inside the get; will raise stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method which mainly should return the current TotalMemoryGB value, unless another value which is TOTALMEORY is not null, as follow:-

```
public double? TotalMemoryGB
        {
            get
            {
                if (TOTALMEMORY != null)
                {

                    return (double)TOTALMEMORY / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
               }

               return TotalMemoryGB;
            }
```

but the above will return a stackoverflow exception, i think since i am return TotalMemoryGB it will keep calling the same method.. so is there a way to fix this ?

**EDIT**

Ok i modify my method as follow:-

private double? _totalmemorygb;

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double? TotalMemoryGB
    {
        get
        {
            if (TOTALMEMORY != null)
            {

                return (double)TOTALMEMORY / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
            }
            else { return _totalmemorygb; }


        }
```

But i will always get the _totalmemorygb as null..

Comment: Your `TotalMemoryGB` property returns your `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` and this returns `TotalMemoryGB` so on..

Comment: @SonerGönül exactly so how i can fix this ? i mean to return the current value .. is there a way ..

Comment: @Abhitalks can u adivce more please?

Comment: Use your backing variable for this property

Comment: and also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798697/system-stackoverflowexception-when-get-set-properties-are-used

Comment: @Abhitalks i tried your appraoch but it did not work ,, can you please check my edit ? now i am using Entity framework as the data access layer..